# A limit for Dirac-delta function using real two sided exponential

Tags: limits, mathematical-physics, dirac-delta

If I have a real-value function (for $x_0 > 0$)
$$
f(x; x_0) = \frac{1}{x_0}\exp\Bigg(-\frac{|x|}{x_0}\Bigg)
$$
If I plot this for different values of $x_0$ it becomes more and more narrow with $x_0 \rightarrow 0$.

[[image: Plots of <span class=]$f(x;x_0)$ for different values of $x_0$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWZIL.png)

Can we prove that this function can be used as a limit representation of Dirac-delta function in the limit $x_0 \rightarrow 0$?

i.e.  Is the following true, and if it is how do we prove it?

$$
\lim_{x_0\rightarrow0}f(x;x_0)=\delta(x)
$$

Comment: [Like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Approximations_to_the_identity). Since we want $f(x,1)$ to have an integral equal to $1$, you just need to divide (the LHS) by two then your last equation is correct

Comment: That means
$$
\lim_{x_0 \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2 x_0}\exp\Bigg(-\frac{|x|}{x_0}\Bigg) = \delta (x)
$$
Am I right?

Comment: Yes, looks good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi\in C_C^\infty$.  Then, the Dominated Convergence Theorem guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0^+}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{e^{-|x|/x_0}}{2x_0}\right)\phi(x)\,dx&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-|x|}\phi(x_0x)\,dx\\\\
&=\phi(0)
\end{align}$$

Therefore, in distribution we have

$$\lim_{x_0\to 0^+}\left(\frac{e^{-|x|/x_0}}{2x_0}\right)=\delta(x)$$

And we are done!